# How to count the unique values of each row in one column with python?

Tags: python, count, unique

I have such a data frame:

```
id countries
01 [UK,UK,UK,US]
02 [US,US,US,US]
03 [FR,UK,CN,US]
```

I want to count how many countries exist for each id. Like the result should be like:

```
id countries counts
01 [UK,UK,UK,US] 2
02 [US,US,US,US] 1
03 [FR,UK,CN,US] 4
```

Comment: Why importing packages when not using them?

Comment: @GarbageCollector um...my fault, it's used for others. I'll delete it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are `list`s convert them to `set` and get `length`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'countries']))
<class 'list'>

df['counts'] = df['countries'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
print (df)
   id         countries  counts
0   1  [UK, UK, UK, US]       2
1   2  [US, US, US, US]       1
2   3  [FR, UK, CN, US]       4
```

Or if values are `strings` first remove `[]` and split:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'countries']))
<class 'str'>

df['counts'] = df['countries'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))
print (df)
   id      countries  counts
0   1  [UK,UK,UK,US]       2
1   2  [US,US,US,US]       1
2   3  [FR,UK,CN,US]       4
```