# Counting the items of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a column called `Similar`. Each row has the following format:

```
[{"Similar":"TEST"},{"Similar":"QWER"},{"Similar":"SEFWEF"},{"Similar":"SFDWEFW"},{"Similar":"WEFWEF"}]
[{"Similar":"SEGWEF"},{"Similar":"WEVWE"},{"Similar":"WECWE"}]  
...
```

When I write

```
len([{"Similar":"TEST"},{"Similar":"QWER"},{"Similar":"SEFWEF"},{"Similar":"SFDWEFW"},{"Similar":"WEFWEF"}] )
```

I get 5. When I write

```
len([{"Similar":"SEGWEF"},{"Similar":"WEVWE"},{"Similar":"WECWE"}])
```

I get 3.

These are the results that I want but for all the column when I write

```
data['Similar']=len(data['Similar'])
```

I get a different number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the length for each array, use `.str.len`:

```
df['Similar'] = df['Similar'].str.len()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Similar
0        5
1        3
```

If you want to get the sum length of all the arrays use `sum` in addition to `.str.len()`:

```
total_sum = df['Similar'].str.len().sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> total_sum
8
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: For the first I get 215, 223...etc., which is not logic since the result have to be between 0 and 7
For the second I get 15940 in every rows

Comment: Are you trying to count unique values of the `Similar` property for each object in each row?

Comment: yes, exactly. As the examples in the question, the result must be 5 and 3

Comment: Thank you for your help, I get inspired from this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900484) to figure out this solution 
`df['Similar']=df['Similar'].str.strip('[]').str.split(pat="}").apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))-1`